# How to verify whether a function has been hit with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest, monkeypatching

I have tried this:

```
def test_send_confirm_hit(monkeypatch):
    hit = False
    def called():
        global hit
        hit = True

    monkeypatch.setattr("web.email.send_confirm", called)

    # ... some event that will cause web.email.send_confirm to be hit

    assert hit  # verify send_confirm was hit
```

Which appears to work although I would rather not use a global variable. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use a `unittest.mock.Mock` and check the `.assert_called()` method.

Comment: I would like to avoid using `unittest`

Comment: You don't have to write unittest tests, you can use it with pytest.

Comment: You could install https://pypi.org/project/mock/ and use `from mock import MagicMock` but that's just a backport for older versions of python, and in newer versions it just aliases to `unittest` anyway ... so don't do that

Comment: @L3viathan That is so helpful and eye-opening! I thought I cannot mix the `pytest` tests with anything from the built-in `unittest` world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a "proper" mock, it comes with an [`.assert_called()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called):

```
import unittest.mock


def test_send_confirm_hit(monkeypatch):
    mock_send_confirm = unittest.mock.Mock()

    monkeypatch.setattr("web.email.send_confirm", mock_send_confirm)

    # ... some event that will cause web.email.send_confirm to be hit

    mock_send_confirm.assert_called()
```

Comment: I have no idea why but this isn't working. I have added a breakpoint when running the tests in debug mode and I know it is calling this method....

Comment: How are you importing `send_confirm` in the function you want to test? If you do `from web.email import send_confirm` the monkeypatching won't work, because the function already has a reference to the real `send_confirm`. Something like `from web import email; email.send_confirm()` will.

Comment: that is so weird I didn't know that was a thing! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Mock instead of the function:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


def test_send_confirm_hit(monkeypatch):
    called = MagicMock()

    monkeypatch.setattr("web.email.send_confirm", called)

    # ... some event that will cause web.email.send_confirm to be hit

    assert called.call_count == 1  # verify send_confirm was hit
```

If you really need to perform some custom logic, like you would do with a function, you can add a `side_effect` to the mock:

```
def test_send_confirm_hit(monkeypatch):
    def side_effect():
        return 42

    called = MagicMock(side_effect=side_effect)
```